# Undeclared type 'UIViewRepresentable' in MacOS project

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I create macOS project and I try to make UIViewRepresentable but get this error.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable { //Error: Use of undeclared type 'UIViewRepresentable'
}
```

What can I do with it or how can I make my own UIViewRepresentable for macOS to use WKWebView in my project?

```swift
struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        WKWebView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`UI...` refers always to UIKit.

For macOS you have to use [NSViewRepresentable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/nsviewrepresentable)

Comment: I couldn't check how NSViewRepresentable work with WKWebView due to other errors when porting my app from Catalyst but now when I launch it I see a black screen instead of the contents of WKWebView. I asked a question about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58175073/wkview-content-doesnt-display-in-nsviewrepresentable)

Answer (score 7):

You can implement the following code. Then Xcode will help you implement correct protocols for corresponding target:

```
#if os(macOS)
public typealias ViewRepresentable = NSViewRepresentable
#elseif os(iOS)
public typealias ViewRepresentable = UIViewRepresentable
#endif
```

#### macOS target

[image: Mac]

---

#### iOS target

[image: iOS]

---

Also, you can have both implementations in one struct like:

```
struct WebView: ViewRepresentable {
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> WKWebView { WKWebView() }
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView { WKWebView() }
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: WKWebView, context: Context) { }
    func updateUIView(_ nsView: WKWebView, context: Context) { }
}
```

---

## Automatic

Check out **[this gist](https://gist.github.com/MojtabaHs/569b4b467aa7a4cea2afcb6736314b23)** if you want to have a simple implementation like this that works in both platforms:

```
import WebKit
struct WebView: ViewRepresentableHelper {
    var configuration = { (view: WKWebView) in }
}
```

#### Usage

```
var body: some View {
    WebView {
        $0.load(request)
    }
}
```