# WKView content doesn't display in NSViewRepresentable

Tags: swiftui

I ran into an issue when I put `WKWebView` in `NSViewRepresentable` then my app shows a black screen instead of the loaded web page.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct TestView : NSViewRepresentable {
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> WKWebView  {
        let view = WKWebView()
        if let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com/") {
            view.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        }
        return view
    }

    func updateNSView(_ view: WKWebView, context: Context) {
    }

}


struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TestView()
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One thing not to oversee on macOS is to turn on "Outgoing Connections" in App Sandbox options.

[image]

Of course "Allow Arbitrary Loads" may be on yes as well.

[image]

If you want to go one step further you should consider to implement a Coordinator as mentioned from LuLuGaGa.

Comment: `Outgoing Connections (Client)` helped me.  Allow Arbitrary Loads needs to allow `http` connection. `Coordinator` is used to send and receive data and does't effect the rendering. Thanks.